# Payment methods not showing in checkout page magento

Tags: payment-methods

I have a website on Magento multi-store view. I am using three payment methods like PayPal, stripe and bank transfer.

On checkout page only PayPal showing remaining two payment methods are not showing. I checked in the admin all three store view setting. everything fine. but I don't know why it's not showing.

I am also using Partial payment extension.

Please, anyone help me.

Comment: Can you tell me which partial payment extension you used?

Comment: https://www.magedelight.com/magento-extensions/partial-payment.html        Above extension iam using

Comment: Verify that you properly set Minimum Order Total, Maximum Order Total, Payment from Applicable Countries configuration for specific method.

Comment: i checked everything fine,  still not working

Comment: On checkout page, when page is load is that any error show in console and log file of magento?

Comment: No error in console and error log related to this one

Comment: Any one please help. serious problem going on with client...

Comment: I have founded solution myself. installed one extension that one caused problem after that removed that extension. now working fine

Answer (score 0):

There could be several reasons why the other two payment methods are not showing on the checkout page. Here are some steps you can take to troubleshoot the issue:

- Check payment method settings: Double-check that the payment methods are enabled in the Magento admin panel for the specific store views. Go to Stores > Configuration > Sales > Payment Methods and make sure that all three payment methods are enabled.
- Clear cache: Clear Magento cache and browser cache. Sometimes payment methods can be hidden due to cache issues.
- Check the Partial Payment extension settings: The Partial Payment extension might be conflicting with the other payment methods. Check the extension settings to ensure that it's not causing any issues.
- Check theme files: If you are using a custom theme, it's possible that the payment methods are not being displayed due to theme files. Check if there are any theme files that might be hiding the payment methods.
- Check payment method availability: Make sure that the payment methods are available for the products in the cart. Some payment methods may only be available for specific products.
- Check server logs: If none of the above steps work, check the server logs for any errors related to the payment methods.

I hope this helps you to troubleshoot the issue. If you still face any issues, you may need to contact a Magento developer or the extension provider for further assistance.